# Token.save is not a function

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, passport.js, passport-local

i am trying to set up passport-remember-me and i am getting a "Token.save is not a function " when i login and check-in the remember me checkbox. Here is the code :

Configuration:

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require("body-parser")
var mongoose = require("mongoose")
var methodOverride = require("method-override")
var passport = require("passport")
var LocalStrategy = require("passport-local").Strategy;
var passportLocalMongoose = require("passport-local-mongoose")
var User = require("./models/user.js")
var RememberMeStrategy = require("passport-remember-me").Strategy;
var utils = require("npm-utils")
var flash = require("connect-flash")
var uid = require('uid2');
var cookieParser = require("cookie-parser")
function generateToken(number) {
   return uid(number);
}

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/rina_app");
//mongoose.connect(process.env.DATABASEURL);
app.use(express.static("public"));

app.use(require("express-session")({
    secret: "Sky",
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false
}))
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(passport.authenticate('remember-me'));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(methodOverride("_method"));
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(User.authenticate()));
passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());
passport.use(new RememberMeStrategy(
  function(token, done) {
    Token.consume(token, function (err, user) {
      if (err) { return done(err); }
      if (!user) { return done(null, false); }
      return done(null, user);
    });
  },
  function(user, done) {
    var token = utils.generateToken(64);
    Token.save(token, { userId: user.id }, function(err) {
      if (err) { return done(err); }
      return done(null, token);
    });
  }
));

app.use(function(req, res, next){
    res.locals.currentUser = req.user;
    next();
})
```

token model:

```
var TokenSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    token: {type: String},
    createDate: {type: Date, default: Date.now}
});

var time = mongoose.model("time", timeSchema);
var Token = mongoose.model("Token", TokenSchema);
```

Login route:

```
app.post('/login', 
  passport.authenticate('local', { failureRedirect: '/login', failureFlash: true }),
  function(req, res, next) {
    // issue a remember me cookie if the option was checked
    if (!req.body.remember_me) { return next(); }

    var token = generateToken(64);
    Token.save(token, { userId: req.user.id }, function(err, done) {
      if (err) { return done(err); }
      res.cookie('remember_me', token, { path: '/', httpOnly: true, maxAge: 604800000 }); // 7 days
      return next();
    });
  },
  function(req, res) {
    res.redirect('/');
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at http://mongoosejs.com/docs/models.html

You need to create a new instance of your model, a 'document', which can then be saved. Inside your login route:

```
var token = new Token({
  userId: req.user.id,
  token: generateToken(64)
});

token.save(function(err) {
  if (err) return next(err);
  res.cookie('remember_me', token, { path: '/', httpOnly: true, maxAge: 604800000 }); // 7 days
  return next();
});
```